# Chocolatey upgrade command is not working

Tags: windows, chocolatey

```
C:\Windows\System32>choco upgrade chocolatey
Chocolatey v1.1.0
Upgrading the following packages:
chocolatey
By upgrading, you accept licenses for the packages.
chocolatey v1.1.0 is the latest version available based on your source(s).

Chocolatey upgraded 0/1 packages.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
```

This is what I got after entering "choco upgrade chocolatey"
Chocolatey upgrade is not working.
Below is the log details.

```
2022-08-07 13:41:31,532 27532 [DEBUG] - _ Chocolatey:ChocolateyUpgradeCommand - Normal Run Mode _
2022-08-07 13:41:31,538 27532 [INFO ] - Upgrading the following packages:
2022-08-07 13:41:31,541 27532 [INFO ] - chocolatey
2022-08-07 13:41:31,544 27532 [INFO ] - By upgrading, you accept licenses for the packages.
2022-08-07 13:41:31,711 27532 [DEBUG] - Using 'https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'.
2022-08-07 13:41:32,064 27532 [DEBUG] - - Supports prereleases? 'True'.
2022-08-07 13:41:32,066 27532 [DEBUG] - - Is ServiceBased? 'True'.
2022-08-07 13:41:32,346 27532 [DEBUG] - Package 'chocolatey' found on source 'https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
2022-08-07 13:41:32,350 27532 [INFO ] - chocolatey v1.1.0 is the latest version available based on your source(s).
2022-08-07 13:41:32,368 27532 [WARN ] - 
Chocolatey upgraded 0/1 packages. 
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
2022-08-07 13:41:32,376 27532 [DEBUG] - Sending message 'PostRunMessage' out if there are subscribers...
2022-08-07 13:41:32,386 27532 [DEBUG] - Exiting with 0
```

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to upgrade Chocolatey CLI v1.1.0.

```
Chocolatey v1.1.0
```

Chocolatey CLI is telling you that the latest version of Chocolatey CLI, available on the Chocolatey Community Repository (https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/) is v1.1.0.

```
chocolatey v1.1.0 is the latest version available based on your source(s).
```

So there is nothing for it to do.

```
Chocolatey upgraded 0/1 packages.
```